# Extract translations from all twig templates (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, twig, gettext

We are using Twig template engine for our CodeIgniter based project. And we faced a problem with translatable strings extractions from twig template.

```
{% trans %}Text to translate{% endtrans %}
```

xgettext can not extract translatable strings from such templates, but it can parse compiled (to php) twig templates and extract translatable strings from there.
So the problem could be solved by making *all* templates compiled to php and then by extracting strings from it.

And here is the question:

How to force Twig to compile set of extensions from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Result of my investigations ended with the following php script. It's intented to be used as follows:

```
./compile_twig_templates.php /path/to/tmp/dir
```

Script will fill tmp dir with compiled templates (pure .php files) that can be parsed by xgettext as usual

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if (!$argv) {
    echo 'Script should be runned from command line';
    exit(1);
}

if ( !$argv[1] ) {
    echo "Usage: ".$argv[0]." path_to_cache_dir\n";
    echo "Example: ".$argv[0]." /tmp/twig_cache\n";
    exit(1);
}

if ( !is_dir($argv[1])) {
    echo "$argv[1] is not a directory";
    exit(1);
}


$script_path = dirname($argv[0]);

require_once 'libraries/Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
require_once (string) "libraries/Twig-extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Autoloader.php";
Twig_Extensions_Autoloader::register();

//path to directory with twig templates
$tplDir = $script_path.'/views';
$tmpDir = $argv[1];
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($tplDir);

// force auto-reload to always have the latest version of the template
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => $tmpDir,
    'auto_reload' => true
));

//add all used extensions
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());

//add all used custom functions (if required)
$twig->addFunction('base_url', new Twig_Function_Function('base_url'));

// Adding PHP helper functions as filters:
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('ceil', 'ceil'));

echo "Iterating over templates!\n";
// iterate over all your templates
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($tplDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $file)
{
    echo "Compiling ".$file."\n";
    // force compilation
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        try {
        $twig->loadTemplate(str_replace($tplDir.'/', '', $file));
        } catch (Twig_Error_Syntax $e) {
            echo "Caught exeption! $e\n";
            var_dump($e);
            exit(2);
        }
    }
}

?>
```